# using Git and pushing to production mode (w/ diagram)

Tags: git, svn, github

[image: steps]

As you see in the diagram, you have the developers pulling code from the `develop` branch and then pushing the code back in as they make updates. Develop branch is tested and then merged with the `master` or `release` branch. Once the merge is complete and the release branch is updated with the new code from all the developers, it's then ready for public.

I understand the Git process and practice of working in order (of course some of you may have other ways of doing so), but how do you guys do it from testing to production mode?

If I have a website called imagesearch.com, and the production files are located in /htdocs/, where on the server would you upload the code and test your develop branch before merging?

*The old fashion way would be using your editor to connect to the ftp, downloading files, modifying them, and then re-uploading them, once uploaded they are live to users on the website.*

**1.** When you push code to the develop branch, how do you upload/test that on the server? (when testing locally is not an option)

**2.** Once it's tested, and you've merged it to the release, how do you push the new code to the production (/htdocs/ in that example)?

I understand how Github works, and Git itself when dealing with a collaboration project and open source where people contribute to a project, but where and how can I find out the best practice when dealing with a production environment. I don't want to upload my files from the directory in which Git is using, that seems like that creates a security risk and possible file issues with Git.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is a bad practice not to run your tests into a test environment before deploying it to production.

But if it is what you want to do, you can deploy the new development in production for testing in an other folder next to htdocs.

To answer your questions this is what I would do

1.1 In order to trace what you are testing you should create a tag of the current state of your master/release  branch.  From your release branch run: git tag your-tag-name

1.2 create an archive of the content of your release branch. It will be the release deliverable. If you have only static content, a zip of the branch is perfect.

1.3 upload the zip to the production server and unzip into you test directory next to the htdocs directory

1.4 make your test directory accessible from the server and test the deliverable from that context path

2. Once you are satisfied of the tests results, stop your server, empty the htdocs directory, unzip your release package to it and start your server again.

Comment: I could see that working in large updates, for like a massive version change to an application. However, I'd like to see the process in which one takes to just simple/quick and small updates. If you changed a few words, maybe a color or a border size. I think to take a system with hundreds of files (including images, css, js, scripts, etc) and unzip them up in that nature would be a lot more work than its worth. But even a change where its a quick "patch" for a bug, coping all those files manually would take more time than its worth.

Comment: I understand better what you are looking for now. You could use an aumation tool like Puppet from https://puppetlabs.com. With such a tool you can deploy to an host from a master place only what has changed.